# White Sceen display before Splash Screen when ionic 2 app run at first time in android platform

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic. so I have faced one issue when my app runs in the Android platform for the first time a white screen is displayed for 2-3 seconds and then the splash screen is loaded.

- I also face issue in "ionic cordova run android --prod" command to build app with production.
- use ionic 2

  ```
  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.2.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
  Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2

  Cordova:

  cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
  Cordova Platforms : android 6.4.0, browser 5.0.4
  Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 26 other plugins)

  System:

  Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 
  NodeJS : v10.11.0 (/usr/bin/node)
  npm : 4.6.1
  OS : Linux 4.15
  ```

Any Solution?

Comment: what is the issue when running with --prod flag?

Comment: when i use "ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss" instead of "ionic cordova run android --prod" white screen show when app install at first time.

Comment: when i use "ionic cordova run android --prod" that time face "Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error and does not generate build APK.

Comment: I had same issue, since last 6 month there is nothing solution. kindly share solution if anybody has. And this issue is now rejecting my app from Apple store